# how can delete items from a list in python and replace them with new items?

Tags: python, list

I am having a problem with replacing a full list with another list.
For example, let's say I have a list that contains the words `['han','san']`;
how can I have another list that has `[1,2]` send its values to replace `han` and `san` in that list?

```
i = [1,2]

p = ['han', 'san']
```

I want to have `han` and `san` replaced with `1` and `2`.

Comment: `for index, item in enumerate(list)` will give you indexes and items

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? Are 'han' and 'san' the only values in p? If 'han' and 'san' are the only values then p = i (as suggested by  5gon12ede) should work.

Comment: yes they are and i am trying to completely delete them and put 1 and 2

Comment: do you only want to replace `han` with 1 and `san` with 2?

Answer (score 1):

```
In [1]: i = [1,2]

In [2]: p = ['han', 'san']

In [3]: i[:] = p # replace all content of i with content of p

In [4]: i
Out[4]: ['han', 'san']
```

If you have a longer list and want just the first two replaced:

```
In [5]: i = [1,2,3,4]

In [6]: p = ['han', 'san']

In [7]: i[:2] = p # replace just first two elements with contents of p

In [8]: i
Out[8]: ['han', 'san', 3, 4]
```

The  `i[:]` syntax selects the whole list, so `i[:] = p` adds every element from `p` to `i`, if you used `i = p` `i` would be a reference to `p` so any changes in p would be reflected in `i` as `i is p`, they both point to the same object in memory.

Using `i[:2]` we are selecting only the first two elements of longer version of `i` and setting them equal to the contents of `p`, if `p` had ten elements we would add ten elements to `i`. When assigning using the `[:]` syntax the right side must *always* be an iterable.

```
In [9]: id(i)
Out[9]: 140380204622192    
In [10]: i[:] = p                        
In [11]: id(i) # still same object
Out[11]: 140380204622192    
In [12]: i = p    
In [13]: id(i) # now i is p
Out[13]: 140380204431624    
In [14]: id(p)
Out[14]: 140380204431624
```

Comment: @JonClements, done but it is way past bedtime so feel free to edit ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
map(lambda x:p[x-1],i)
```

is one way

Comment: any other easier way than that? for example like p = d will replace that? -_- i am pretty new to the game

Answer (score 0):

Using an operation such as:

```
p = d
```

Would work for your example, but it would replace one list with the other rather than replace each item with another list's items. You could try Joran Beasley's method mentioned earlier:

```
map(lambda x: p[x - 1], i)
```

Or you could define a function:

```
def replace_list(old_list, new_list):
    for x in range(len(old_list)):
        old_list[x] = new_list[x]
```

As you can see, there are various methods for replacing the items in a list, and your choice really depends on your program. Hope this helped!

Comment: try changing d after you assign p = d and then look at p